# Swapping 2 columns with Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have 2 columns, separated by comma.  How can I swap those columns with Emacs?

I have the following:

```
  column 1,column2
  x1,x2
  y1,y2
  f1,f2
```

and I want it like this:

```
 column2,column 1
 x2,x1
 y2,y1
 f2,f1
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `M-x query-replace-regexp` and then:

```
\(.+\),\(.+\)
```

as replace regexp and

```
\2,\1
```

for replacement.

---

In Emacs, you need to escape grouping parentheses with `\`. So, above regexp would be usually written as

```
(.+),(.+)
```

which means that you want everything before comma in first group and everything after comma in second group.

```
\2,\1
```

means: write second group, then comma, then first group.

Comment: +1 for regexp - I love emacs regular expression. What really rocks with them is that you can match linefeeds with them as well.

Answer (score 6):

While you can apply techniques given by other people, you can also use the org-mode tables.
Once you convert the data into org-mode table, it is very easy to swap the columns by simple keystrokes.  You can have M-x org-mode,  select the region then do M-x org-table-convert-region, and then M- on the right most column. I am not sure, how to export the data as CSV, but that should be very easy for you with replace-regexp.  This can be helpful: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Tables.html#Tables

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the answer given by @darioo, type the following into the top of your buffer:

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\(.*?\\),\\(.*\\)" "\\2,\\1")
```

Then, put your cursor at the end of this line and press ctrl-x, ctrl-e.

You will have an interactive search-and-replace for which you press the space bar to make the change, and press ctrl-g to quit. If you press `!` (exclamation mark) then the search will cease being interactive and take place on all matching text.

If you want to reverse the changes then press M-x (usually ESC followed by `x`) and type `undo` and press enter.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs has a rectangular selection mode, see for example: http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2008/12/working-with-rectangular-selections.html

Even better, if you enable cua-mode, entering Ctrl-Enter will put you in rectangle selection mode that is very easy to use.

http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/10/emacs-tip-26-cua-mode-specifically.html

Answer (score 3):

Use a macro !

- Go to the first line of the buffer
- Start recording a macro (F3)
- Move to the beginning of the line (^a)
- Search for comma (^s ,)
- Transpose (M-t)
- Move cursor down one line
- Stop recording macro (F4)

Select the rest of the lines and:

```
M-x apply-macro-to-region-lines
```

UPDATE: This doesn't work properly if you have multiple words in a column. Looking for a more general solution...